# Getting errors from system console while Pycharm console executes code correctly

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

This is very simple code, and I'm not sure what's causing the breakage.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

Location = 'r/home/michael/PycharmProjects/cmsDataProject/inpatientProviderPaymentSummary.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(Location, header=False)

print df.info()
```

and when I run it in the Pycharm console, I get:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/michael/PycharmProjects/cmsDataProject/IngestCSV.py
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 163065 entries, 0 to 163064
Data columns (total 12 columns):
DRG Definition                          163065 non-null object
Provider Id                             163065 non-null int64
Provider Name                           163065 non-null object
Provider Street Address                 163065 non-null object
Provider City                           163065 non-null object
Provider State                          163065 non-null object
Provider Zip Code                       163065 non-null int64
Hospital Referral Region Description    163065 non-null object
 Total Discharges                       163065 non-null int64
 Average Covered Charges                163065 non-null object
 Average Total Payments                 163065 non-null object
Average Medicare Payments               163065 non-null object
dtypes: int64(3), object(9)
memory usage: 16.2+ MB
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Which is the output I should get.

When I run the same code with `/cmsDataProject/>python IngestCSV.py` I get:

```
File "IngestCSV.py", line 9
    print df.info()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What gives? Can they be using a different version of the interpreter somehow?

Comment: What if you run it exactly as Pycharm console does - `/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/michael/PycharmProjects/cmsDataProject/IngestCSV.py` in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default `>python` is probably calling Python 3, which requires parentheses for `print`. Pycharm indicates that it uses Python 2.7. Try `print(df.info())` instead.

Comment: This is in line with what Roman was suggesting above; it does look like my console is defaulting to Python 3.4 instead of 2.7. Off to go research how to change that.